# How to create a sparse or NxM matrix using scikits learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a spare array that looks like this

```
N  M
a cat
b cat
c cat
a dog
d dog
e dog
```

I need to represent in this format:

```
   cat dog
a   1   1
b   1   0
c   1   0
d   0   1
e   0   1
```

Using scikits-learn how do I do that?

My raw data looks like this:

```
[{"N":"a"},{"M":"cat"},{"N":"a"},{"M":"dog"}...]
```

The cells but be binary and will be used for nmf algo.

If I run the below:

```
data = [{"N":"a"},{"M":"cat"},{"N":"a"},{"M":"dog"}]
v = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)

    [[ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]]
```

but it should look this:

```
1 1
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use a label encoder. Alternatively, load your data into a sparse dataframe and call `get_dummies`. Do you have pandas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you just need to use "M" column to build the encoding.

```
v = DictVectorizer(sparse=False) # sparse=False now
data = [{"N":"a"},{"M":"cat"},{"N":"a"},{"M":"dog"}]
filtered_data = (d for d in data if "M" in d.keys()) # filter out "N"
v.fit_transform(filtered_data)
# output
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

Do it *pandas'* way.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([df.N, df.M.str.get_dummies()], axis=1)

    N  cat dog
0   a   1   0
1   b   1   0
2   c   1   0
3   a   0   1
4   d   0   1
5   e   0   1
```

`df.M.str.get_dummies()` will generate:

```
   cat  dog
0   1   0
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   0   1
4   0   1
5   0   1
```